# How do I take a file in my own repository in github?

Tags: github

I'm currently having bugs with my file and so I want to redo everything. I want to take what I have previously uploaded in github and start again with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to `https://github.com/username/repository-name`
2. Click the **green** "Code" button
3. Click "Download ZIP"
4. Unzip the downloaded file
5. Start agian

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to update the repo using the new file that I started? Or do I have to create a new repository for it again?

Comment: It is possible, check out [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) for more detail